# Calculate probability density function of difference of two random distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

I want to calculate probability density function (PDF) of $Z=X-Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
The distribution of $X$ is given by the following equation:

$$f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma{(\alpha_{x})}\beta_{x}^{\alpha_{x}}}\ x^{\alpha_{x}-1}\ e^{\left(-\frac{x}{\beta_{x}}\right)},$$

where $\alpha_{x}>0, \beta_{x}>0 $.

The distribution of $Y$ is given by the following equation:

$$ f_{Y}(y)=\frac{\beta_{y}}{\alpha_{y}\Gamma(1/\beta_{y})}\ y \ e^{-\left(\frac{|y^{2}-\mu|}{\alpha_{y}}\right)^{\beta_{y}}},$$

where $\alpha_{y}>0, \beta_{y}>0 $.

And, random variable $X$ and $Y$ are $ x>y>0 $.

I tried this by using convolution. But, it is so complicated… And also I tried calculation of characteristic function of $Y$. But that is also complicated. How can I get this PDF of $Z$?

Comment: You should post what you have done so far. Others can then help you identify your mistake.

Comment: $$
f_Z(t) = (f_X\star f_{-Y})(t) = \int_{\mathbb R} f_X(s)f_{-Y}(t-s)\ \mathsf ds,
$$
where $f_{-Y}$ is the density of $-Y$.

Comment: I already done that. but it is so complicated to calculate.. So I want to know some technique for this integration.